# Proof applying compactness theorem.

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am trying to work out the next proof:

Let $\Sigma$ be a set of formulas. Assume $$\Sigma \vDash \bigvee_{i \in I} \varphi_i \ \leftrightarrow \ \bigwedge_{j \in J} \psi_j $$ 
Where $\varphi_i$ and $\psi_j$ are formulas. This means that for each $M$ and assignment $s$, such that $M \vDash \Sigma(s)$ then $M \vDash \varphi_i(s)$ for all $i \in I$ iff there is some $j\in J$ such that $M \vDash \psi_j(s)$. Apply compactness to show that there are finite subsets $I' \subseteq I$ and $J' \subseteq J$ such that $$\Sigma \vDash \bigvee_{i \in I} \varphi_i \ \leftrightarrow \ \bigvee_{i \in I'} \varphi_i, \ \ \Sigma \vDash \bigvee_{i \in I'} \varphi_i \ \leftrightarrow \ \bigwedge_{j \in J'} \psi_j $$

Now, I know I pretty much have to do for things, the first two is to prove $\Sigma \vDash \bigvee_{i \in I} \varphi_i \ \leftrightarrow \ \bigvee_{i \in I'} \varphi_i$. I think I don't even need compactness yet, the right to left direction is "evident", if I have a model for a finite subset (smaller thing), it means I also have one for the complete one, I would appreciate any ideas on how to say this a bit more formally? Now, when I go to the other direction is that I start having issues, I know that intuitively I need to prove that if I have it for the subset I can have it for the entire set, but I don't know how to procede.

For the second part,  $\Sigma \vDash \bigvee_{i \in I'} \varphi_i \ \leftrightarrow \ \bigwedge_{j \in J'} \psi_j$, well, I get that I need to use compactness theorem to assume that there is a finite model for each of the things. And from that finite model, but I have issues formalising it, and getting it in shape. I would very much appreciate anyones input on how to go about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Instead of formulas, think about (clopen) subsets of type spaces corresponding to them. Then just apply topological compactness.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but to be honest, I don't have a background on topology, I don't really know what those concepts are about (or how to go about them).

Comment: @Sara: I'd suggest improving on that front, then. Without elementary knowledge of general topology, many important aspects of model theory will be unavailable to you. To avoid topology in this case, you can think about an element satisfying all $\psi_j$ but none of a finite number of $\varphi_i$.

Comment: The topology point of view is interesting, I will definitely look into it. About this one, so I can do something similar to $\Sigma \cup \{\neg \phi_1 :i \in I \} \vDash \psi_j$??

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help. Instead, think about $\Sigma\cup\{\neg\varphi_i,\psi_j\mid i\in I, j\in J\}$.

Comment: Ok, that one would make the $\psi$ conjunction true, while the $\varphi$ disjunction is false. I think I'm intuitively getting it, but I'm not sure how I can argue that this works. Thank you for helping me understand this problem better.

Comment: I don't think this answer is helpful.

Comment: @Sara: Since it would make the $\psi$ conjunction true and the $\varphi$ disjunction false, it’s inconsistent. That means that there must be finite $I'\subseteq I$ and $J'\subseteq J$ such that $\Sigma\cup\{\neg\varphi_i:i\in I'\}\cup\{\psi_j:j\in J'\}$ is inconsistent. Does that help?

Comment: @C-S: Whether it’s helpful depends entirely on whether one is familiar with the notion of a type space. It wasn’t helpful to the OP, but it could be extremely helpful to someone else.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Those are my thoughts, exactly, though it is always nicer when someone else argues in your defence. (My thoughts about the hint, too, though I figured from Sara's comment that she's going to go and ponder some more on her own, which is why I have not given further hints.)

Comment: Yes, I agree it's helpful to have it as part of the page for anyone else solving the problems from that approach, which seems fairly common, even if it's not mine. Thank you tomasz and @BrianM.Scott, the approach to this kind of problems is much clearer now with your help.